# A list of queues

Tags: c, list, queue

Consider a ticket booking system. A reservation is characterized by category (char), ID, (int), name (max 35 char). Implement a data structure based on linked lists that is efficient from the execution time point of view, with the following components: each category will be a node in the list, and each category will contain a queue (FIFO) statically implemented which contains the reservation request for that category. Implement the functions:

1. Add category
2. Add ticket request - (enque)
3. Serve ticket request - (deque)
4. Display the contents of the list

Here is my code so far:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<ctype.h>
#include<string.h>

struct rev
{
    char category[100],name[35];
    int ID;
    struct rev* next;
};


}
struct rev* newNode(int ID,const char *category,const char *name)
{
    struct rev* new_node = (struct rev*)malloc(sizeof(struct rev));
    
    strcpy(new_node->category,cateogyr);
    strcpy(new_node->name,name);
    new_node->ID=ID;

    new_node->next=NULL;

    return new_node;
}
```

I don't understand exactly what I'm suppose to do.I have tried to implement a list,but I don't know if it has to have just the category.

Comment: regarding: `strcpy(new_node->category,cateogyr);  `catteogy`is miss spelled  Please copy/paste your code,  do not retype the code

Answer (score -1):

Here is an explanation of what the structure and individual operations should be. You are asked to implement a list of queues. Each node in the list will represent a category and will have a field that is a queue of the ticket reservations. Here are what the operations should do:

1. Adding a category will add a node in the list, the corresponding queue will be empty
2. Adding a ticket request will iterate over the list, find the node with the given category and enque in the corresponding queue
3. Serving a ticket request will iterate over the list, find the node with the given category and deque in the corresponding queue
4. Will have to print the list (here it is not clear what is the desired format).

Comment: Regarding 4 I don't really understand how i am supposed to write that,all I have figured out so far is:void create_category(struct rev** ref_head,struct rev *new_node)
{
  new_node->next = (*ref_head);
  (*ref_head) = new_node;

}
struct rev* newNode(struct rev **ref_head,const char *category,struct queue *queue)
{
    struct rev* new_node = (struct rev*)malloc(sizeof(struct rev));
   
   strcpy(new_node->category,category);
   new_node->counter=0;
   new_node->queue=1;

 new_node->next=NULL;

    return new_node;
}   And idk if it is correct or not

Comment: From what you provided it seems you are free to choose the representation but in short I assume you are expected to print the category for each list entry and then the elements in the corresponding queue

Comment: Maybe you give me a site in order to have a model or at least something similiar?

Comment: @pppppp123 I am not sure what you mean by `to have a model` in this context

Comment: Please post clarifications to your question as part of the question rather than as an answer

Comment: @user3629249 this is an answer, not clarification to the question and I have not posted the original question

Answer (score -2):

You can use c++ STL List Library and like vector-tuple you can create your own linkedlist structure(of category type) and implement another structure(of type queue inside) your category type linked list structure and maintain linked list rules of traversing and whenever you want to perform operations on queue just first use traversing of linked list and get on the node and then use queue operation...

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: The questions is specifically about `c` not `c++` this answer is not relevant